# Laravel breeze can't work at safari 11 or safari 13

Tags: laravel, vue.js, safari, breeze

platform: php 8.2, laravel 10

When install Laravel breeze：

`composer create-project laravel/laravel`

`composer require laravel/breeze:* --dev`

`php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr`

`npm install & npm run dev`

When open the site's home page.It's ok at chrome and firefox,and safari 16 and safari 17.But it not work at safari 11 and safari 13. It is blank page.
I have tried install @vitejs/plugin-legacy.But it also show blank page.

Comment: what is it showing in console or network tab?